# Is it possible Refund the ETH within ERC20 Contracts?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

if user sent the 1.5 ETH then accepted the 1 ETH, but 0.5 ETH should be refunded to sender. 
I tried like `msg.sender.transfer(0.5)`

and tried like `msg.sender.transfer(500000000000000000)`

but nothing happened.  I am not sure about that msg.sender.transfer is a right function.

is it possible do such way in Contracts?

Comment: which version of solidity are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Change `0.5` to `0.5 ether` or to `500000000000000000`.

Comment: tried msg.sender.transfer(500000000000000000) but its not refund the ether.

Comment: @aumkii did you check the actual balances? The transaction will still show as sending 1.5 eth, but the balance will only be 1 eth less after the transaction

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  sending 1.5, so deducted 1.5 ETH from my account and credited to another 1.5 ETH account. `owner.transfer(1.5 ether) ;`  its working fine.  but `msg.sender.transfer(500000000000000000)` is not working.. its not credit 0.5 ether in my account.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit more complete answer: Solidity (and Ethereum) handle only full integers and no decimals in Ether values. All transactions happen in *Wei* which is the smallest unit of Ether (the cryptocurrency).

One *Ether* equals to 1000000000000000000 *Wei*s - that is 10^18 *Wei*s.

Therefore, whenever you want to transfer value withing the Ethereum blockchain, you use *Wei*s as the amount and calculate the correct amount. So, in your case, `0.5 Ethers = 500000000000000000 Weis`.

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function takes as parameter to transfer in `wei`, so in order to send `0.5 ether` you will have to transfer `500000000000000000 wei`. And the parameter has to be an `interger`.

Answer (score 0):

`msg.sender.transfer(0.5 ether);` may not be worked in modern versions of solidity.

`transfer` function can only be called in `payable` addresses.
So following code will work.
`payable(address(msg.sender)).transfer(0.5 ether);`